# Show just two lines in lm-sensors

Tags: bash, conky, lm-sensors

I want to add lm-sensors to my conky setup, but it always shows this:

`coretemp-isa-0000`
`Adapter: ISA adapter`
`Physical id 0:  +41.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)`
`Core 0:         +41.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)`
`Core 1:         +40.0°C  (high = +82.0°C, crit = +102.0°C)`

I want to have just to lines (for the two cores) in conky. Is there some way to either tell sensors to display just those to lines, or make conky do it or something?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sensors | tail -n3 | head -n2
```

`tail -n3` will output the last 3 lines (there's an empty line at the end), then `head -n2` will output the 2 first lines you want (and discard the empty one).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to only filter the lines that start with `Core X:` where `X` is any number like so:

```
sensors | grep '^Core\s[[:digit:]]\+:'
```